# Why the passed parameter does not work in my shell script？

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script to check whether the process is running:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
ps -ef|grep $var|grep -v grep > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo $var is running!
else
    echo $var is not running!
fi
```

However, no matter what parameters I enter in the command line, the result always shows "*xxx is running!*". As shown below:

```
[test@XXXserver ~]$ sh check.sh 23ljfado
23ljfado is running!
```

But if I assign the parameter directly in the script, the result is displayed correctly. For example, if the variable **var** is changed to **var=23ljfado** in the script, then the result is shown as below:

```
[test@XXXserver ~]$ sh check.sh
23ljfado is not running!
```

If I change **var** to the process that is running, for example, let **var=python** in the script, then the result is "*python is running!*"

I hope this variable can be passed into the script through the command-line parameter, but why the passed parameter does not work in my shell script？

Comment: Why not use `pgrep` rather than piping `ps` to `grep`?

Comment: Check if your script file has `\r\n` line endings. `cat -A check.sh`

Comment: Try removing the `> /dev/null` so you can see what it's finding in the process list. My bet is that your script is finding itself in the `ps` list. That is, if you run `sh check.sh 23ljfado`, then the `ps` output will include both `sh check.sh 23ljfado` and `grep 23ljfado`; `grep -v grep` eliminate the second, but not the first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ps output also includes the shell script and its parameter that would make the check failed. In this case you will have to provide one more condition to eliminate itself

```
#!/bin/bash
var="$1"
name=$(basename $0)
ps -ef|grep $var|grep -v -e grep -e $name > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo $var is running!
else
    echo $var is not running!
fi
```